# Custom Adapter error in getView()

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a `Custom` adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`, it's for a Navigation Drawer.

But for some reason once I set my listview adapter I get an error; `NullPointException`; in the `getView()` method, where I declare the `ImageView`.
Despite many researches I can't understand why. Anyone knows?
the App uses support `v7` and `ActionBarActivity`

Thx!

```
public class DrawerItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 Context mContext;
 int mLayoutResourceId;
 ObjectDrawerItem mData[] = null;


// Constructor
public DrawerItemAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ObjectDrawerItem[] data) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mLayoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mData = data;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItem = convertView;
    ObjectDrawerItem objectDrawerItem = mData[position];

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((ActionBarActivity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

    ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.drawer_item_icon);
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.drawer_item_title);

    iconImageView.setImageDrawable(listItem.getResources().getDrawable(objectDrawerItem.getmIcon()));
    titleTextView.setText(objectDrawerItem.getmTitle());

    return listItem;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at this line:
`inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);`

You seem to have forgotten to assign the returned view to `listItem`

Comment: `listItem = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);` and I think your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

use inflater.findViewById()...

```
 ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView) inflater.findViewById(R.id.drawer_item_icon);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) inflater.findViewById(R.id.drawer_item_title);
```

change your code with this.